# mysql find and replace

Tags: mysql, replace

I'm trying to replace a bunch of no UTF-8 characters

> ie/ â€™

Here's my query:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_act` WHERE `actDesc` LIKE '%â€™%' -
```

How can I form this to 'Find And Replace' with the characters: "\'" ???

Answer (score 5):

```
update [table_name] 
set [field_name]=replace([field_name],'[string_to_find]','[string_to_replace]');
```

Referred from http://www.mediacollege.com/computer/database/mysql/find-replace.html